# Modem not responding wvdial ubuntu 15.10

Tags: internet, usb-modem, wvdial, cdma

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 yesterday(22 dec,2015).

I installed wvdial and made some changes to /etc/wvdial.conf file.
    Connected my usb cdma 1x modem with usim of UTL Nepal. Then i typed sudo wvdial and pressed enter key. The connection was established as it showed ip addresses and dns . But still i was unable to use internet.

I turned off the computer and later started computer and connected the modem.But this time when i typed sudo wvdial, i got following message:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATE0
--> Sending: ATQ0
--> Re-Sending: ATE0
--> Modem not responding.
```

i googled for solution , followed several links but was unable to solve this problem. Please help me.

The contents of /etc/wvdial.conf is:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Baud = 230400
Init1 = ATE0
#Init2 = AT$PBTYPE=1 RPTCON=1 MTRPTTYPE=3 SMSRUIM=0 SMSTYPE=1
Init3 = AT+CTA=0
Init4 = ATEOV1
Init5 = AT
Init6 = ATS0=0
ISDN = 0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Phone = #777
Username = 9723368036@utlnepal.com
Password = 9723368036
Stupid Mode = 1
New PPPD = yes
```

I have mentioned details of modem below:

after I run:lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:055d Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

"067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port" is for my cdma modem

after i entered following command:

```
sudo modprobe cdc_acm
dmesg | tail
```

i got following message:

```
[17379.575320] usbserial_generic 1-3:1.0: device disconnected
[17382.501202] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[17382.629856] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
[17382.629864] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[17382.629869] usb 1-3: Product: USB-Serial Controller
[17382.629873] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[17382.630503] usbserial_generic 1-3:1.0: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.
[17382.630509] usbserial_generic 1-3:1.0: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.
[17382.630513] usbserial_generic 1-3:1.0: generic converter detected
[17382.630669] usb 1-3: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

So please help me.....

I tried using pppd , I typed sudo pppconfig and pressed enter.

I followed the instruction on the screen and set up a configuration named providerUTL.

Then I typed pon providerUTL
it gave no message.

I typed plog and got message:

```
Dec 26 22:05:10 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: abort on (BUSY)
Dec 26 22:05:10 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: abort on (NO CARRIER)
Dec 26 22:05:10 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: abort on (VOICE)
Dec 26 22:05:10 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: abort on (NO DIALTONE)
Dec 26 22:05:10 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: abort on (NO DIAL TONE)
Dec 26 22:05:10 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: abort on (NO ANSWER)
Dec 26 22:05:10 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: abort on (DELAYED)
Dec 26 22:05:10 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: send (ATZ^M)
Dec 26 22:05:10 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: expect (OK)
```

still no connection

I typed poff and then plog and got following message:

```
Dec 26 22:05:10 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: expect (OK)
Dec 26 22:05:55 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: alarm
Dec 26 22:05:55 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: send (AT^M)
Dec 26 22:05:55 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: expect (OK)
Dec 26 22:06:40 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: alarm
Dec 26 22:06:40 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 chat[4096]: Failed
Dec 26 22:06:40 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 pppd[4094]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/providerUTL finished (pid 4095), status = 0x3
Dec 26 22:06:40 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 pppd[4094]: Connect script failed
Dec 26 22:06:41 gulshan-Lenovo-G40-70 pppd[4094]: Exit.
```

Comment: the message displayed after typing dmesg | tail command contains this line: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver. So, I tried sending email to linux-usb@vger.kernel.org but automated reply says my mail cannot be accepted as it contains html tags but i have not added any html element in my mail. Is any one familiar with this??

Comment: I decided to test if it works in older versions of Ubuntu. I tried on my friends laptop running Ubuntu 14.04(64bit) but had same problem, Modem not responding.

He had iso of Ubuntu 13.04(64bit) so I made a bootable usb stick , booted it on my Laptop, installed wvdial , changed Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0 and I got connected!!

So I would like suggestion for making it work in Ubuntu 15.10.